# Ensure valid package version is used when building assets with webpack

Tags: npm, gulp, webpack

We are building our assets with webpack. Recently I had to update graft-js-plugins-editor from 2.0.0-beta1 to 2.0.0-beta5. When my college pulled the change they forgot to run `npm install` before building the assets and deployed the old version of the package

How can we ensure that the version specified in package.json is used to build the assets?

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "build-production": "gulp production"
}

// Gulpfile
gulp.task('production', ['clean', 'mkdir-assets', 'webpack-production']);
...
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('webpack-production', function(){
  return gulp.src(config.webpack.src)
    .pipe(webpackStream(config.webpack.production))
    .pipe(assetManifest(config.assetManifest.js))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.webpack.dest));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like [gulp-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-install) as the very first task to your `build-production` script?

Comment: Thank you @elektronik for this elegant solution. The first idea which came up in my head was to change the `"build-production": "npm install && gulp production"`